# How to test a $uibModal instance controller?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, bootstrap-modal, angular-controller

I'm trying to test a certain controller functionality with Jasmine unit testing.

I have a function which opens a modal instance with a **new controller**:

```
function openFilterModal(data) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        controller: FilterModalController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        resolve: {
            data: function () {
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
    return modalInstance.result;
}
```

The controller is defined below:

```
FilterModalController.$inject = ['alertsModalService', '$uibModalInstance', 'data', '$scope', 'logger', '$timeout'];

    function FilterModalController(alertsModalService, $uibModalInstance, data, $scope, logger, $timeout) { 
// code goes here }
```

When I try to call 'openFilterModal', I'm unable to get the controller instance, just getting the promise from it.
I've tried to used the $controller(FilterModalController) function in Jasmine, but it couldn't find the controller.

What is the best practice in that case?
Should I add the controller definition to my module? right now it defined like anonymous controller... not sure if that's good behavior or not.

like that:

```
app.controller('FilterModalController', FilterModalController);
```

Is it ok to define 2 controllers on the same module?
Or there is another way to get test the controller?

Thanks!